# Can I add a room number to an event's location?

Tags: calendar, geolocation

Suppose I have an event at a building of which the location can find the address so I get a nice travel time estimate. Problem is, the building contains an awful lot of rooms and I'd really like to add the room number to the location (as that shows up in my overview).

So how can I add the room number to the location without the automatic travel time estimates breaking?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't since Calendar always auto-completes to something without additional room/extra info. Alternatively put the room in the notes.